# Google App Engine (Python) - Getting Datastore error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a notes page where at the bottom I have an input where I can leave myself topics of what to look into and it will post to below the input. I'm fairly new to programming and I'm running into errors. I'd like to store the Comments in Datastore but I can't seem to get it to work. I get this error:

InternalError: no such table: *projectname*!!Entities

Any help? What am I doing wrong. I can supply my app.yaml or index.yaml page if needed.

Here is the input portion of my HTML index template page:

```
 <form method="post">
     <input type="text" name="comment" size="40" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; text-align:center" >
     {% if items %}
         {% for item in items %}
            <input type="hidden" name="comment" value="{{item}}">
         {% endfor %}
     {% endif %}
     <br>
     <button style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">Add</button>

     {% if items %}
         <h3 class="idea-name" style="text-align:center">Topics to look into</h3>
         <ul>
           {% for item in items %}
                <li>{{ item }}</li>
           {% endfor %}
         </ul>
     {% endif %}
 </form>
```

Here is my main.py file:

```
import jinja2
import webapp2 
import os

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates') 
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)


class Comment(ndb.Model):
    content = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
      self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
      t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
      return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
      self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
      query = Comment.query().order(Comment.date)
      for comment in query:
        content = comment.content
        self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % self.comment.content)
      self.render("index.html")

    def post(self):
        content = self.request.get('content')
        comment = Comment(content = content)
        comment.put()
        import time
        time.sleep(.1)
        self.redirect('/')


class Unit0Page(Handler):
    def get(self):
  self.render("unit0.html")

class Unit1Page(Handler):
    def get(self):
      self.render("unit1.html")

class Unit2Page(Handler):
    def get(self):
      self.render("unit2.html")

class Unit3Page(Handler):
    def get(self):
      self.render("unit3.html")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/unit0.html', Unit0Page),
    ('/unit1.html', Unit1Page),
    ('/unit2.html', Unit2Page),
    ('/unit3.html', Unit3Page)], debug=True)
```

Comment: I suggest you include the stacktrace.  The error looks odd unless it's related to projections.

Comment: you can only write once to the response object, so having it in that loop is inappropriate.

Comment: @user2266449 are you suggesting that self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % self.comment.content) and  self.render("index.html") should be combined?

Comment: yes, I can't remember offhand what render does but I think it's just shorthand for another write to the response object.